# Quickly loop over pixels numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to do the following loop through an image to remove or modify a pixel if it equals rgb value with threshold.

The goal is to remove the background of an image and feed the image to an OCR.

I have tried 2 different methods to do this.

Method 1:

Basically what I do is get the average background pixel value. 
And than loop over all pixels and check which pixels equal the average background pixel.

```
    for x in range(0, w):
        for y in range(0, h):
            if Pixel(img[y, x]).compare(pixel, threshold):
                img[y, x] = 255
            else
                img[y, x] = 0
```

compare function will check if it >=/<= the pixel -/+ the threshold value. then if it returns true it will change the pixel to white else to black.

This works well however it is wayyyy too slow when you use bigger pictures.

Method 2:
Just use an opencv method to remove the background.

Simply:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 41, 2)
```

Results:
Feed normal image:
[image]

result method 1:
[image]

result method 2:
[image]

Feed inverted image:
[image]

result method 1:
[image]

result method 2:
[image]

The first method is way to slow and the second method only works when the image has a whitish background I guess.

I do need it for different background colors.

I found something about vectorizing the numpy array. But couldn't really found a good example about it.

Comment: yes sorry my mistake it is a numpy array

Comment: what about using `cv2.threshold` or `cv2.inRange`?

Comment: To zero all values below a certain threshold, just use a mask: img[img <= threshold] = 0. No loop needed, unless you really need to use that Pixel object for another reason

Comment: @Miki I think what I need is inRange, just convert the rgb to proper hsv values.

Comment: @andrew could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: I don’t like typing on a tablet, but here goes.

Comment: I don’t like typing on a tablet, but here goes. I presume your array has a third axis, holding the rgb values. You can get a grayscale single value from that, and then define your threshold (probably the average of the lower 1/4 of pixels. Feed that into img[img<= threshold] and that defines all values less than or equal to that. Assign 0 will increase the contrast in the way you are trying. Or assign 255 for the upper 1/4 in the converse case (though I would probably just invert the image to make all images have a light background

Comment: @Andrew that indeed did the trick thanks allot! First it took 2 seconds, using grayscale lowered the time to 0.8 and without the for loop it takes 0.0004 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question with concrete example:

```
    #load an image as grayscale
    #get the background average pixel value, it out of the scope of this question, different methods to achieve
    bg_avg = get_bg_avg_px_val(img)
    th = 80

    background_mask = logical_and((bg_avg - th) <= img, img <= (bg_avg + th))
    text_mask = logical_or((bg_avg - th) >= img, img >= (bg_avg + th))
    img[selected] = 255
    img[text] = 0
```

Comment: this. If you're looping over a numpy array you're probably doing it wrong : )

Comment: @kevinkayaks what do you mean?